# How to show a message if there isn't any SQL Exceptions

Tags: c#, sql, exception, try-catch

I want to simply notify the user that they have successfully inserted new data to a database.

This is what I have so far:

```
try { cont.NewMember(txtSS.Text, txtName.Text, txtCity.Text, txtStreet.Text, txtZipcode.Text, txtEmail.Text, txtPhone.Text); }
catch (SqlException ex) { MessageBox.Show("The social security number \"" + txtSS.Text + "\"is already registered"); }

MessageBox.Show("Added succesfully");
```

I want to show the "Added successfully" only if (obviously) there wasn't an Exception. The update itself is working fine but the message "Added..." is always showing (even when there was an exception).

How can I solve this, using C#?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

put the `MessageBox...` statement at the end of  the `try` block

```
try 
{ 
    cont.NewMember(txtSS.Text, txtName.Text, txtCity.Text, txtStreet.Text, txtZipcode.Text, txtEmail.Text, txtPhone.Text);
    MessageBox.Show("Added succesfully"); 
}
catch (SqlException ex) 
{ 
    MessageBox.Show("The social security number \"" + txtSS.Text + "\"is already registered"); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this is not the correct approach. how would you know that the exception is because the SSN already existed in the database. It could throw an exception for many other cases like connection failure etc...

the best practice is to handle all these in the database.

Refer to handling exceptions in the database.